# Prevent to display blank subcategoy in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I create three table upfiles(contains Category)->subtable(contains id of category and subcategory)->billtable(contains id of subcategory and bills)

How do I prevent subcategory to display in php mysql who does not have its child in this case is bill name below is my code

```
echo '<ul>';
$year_query = "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR (uploaddate) AS OrderYear FROM billTable  
               WHERE username='$log_username' ORDER BY uploaddate ASC ";
$result_year_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $year_query);
echo $e2= mysqli_error($db_conx );
while ( $year_query = mysqli_fetch_row($result_year_query)) {
    $year_query = $year_query[0];
    echo "<li>$year_query<br/>";
    echo '<ul>';                
    $month_query = "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(uploaddate) AS OrderMONTH FROM billTable 
                    WHERE username='$log_username' 
                    AND year(uploaddate) = '$year_query' ORDER BY uploaddate ASC ";
    $result_month_query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $month_query);
    while ( $month_query = mysqli_fetch_row($result_month_query)) {
        $month_query = $month_query[0];
        echo "<li>$month_query<br/>";
        echo '<ul>';                            
        $bill_query = "SELECT * FROM billTable WHERE username='$log_username'  
                       AND month(uploaddate) = '$month_query' 
                       AND year(uploaddate) = '$year_query' ORDER BY cname ASC " ;
        $bill_result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $bill_query);
        while ( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($bill_result)) {
            $idSubCat_billTable= $row1[7];// subtale id
            $tempfilename= $row1[10];
            $Cquery = "SELECT * FROM subtable WHERE username='$log_username' 
                       AND id = '$idSubCat_billTable '  ";
            $result_upfiles = mysqli_query($db_conx, $Cquery);
            while ( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result_upfiles)){
                $idSubCat_subtable = $row2[0];
                $rowId = $row2[3]; //id of ctaegory
                $Cquery = "SELECT  * FROM upfiles WHERE username='$log_username'  
                           AND id = '$rowId ' ORDER BY categories ASC " ;
                $result_upfiles = mysqli_query($db_conx, $Cquery);
                while ( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result_upfiles)) {
                    $rowId = $row2[0]; //id
                    $rowCat = $row2[7]; //Categorie value
                    echo "<li>$rowCat<br/>";
                    echo '<ul>';
                    if ($idSubCat_billTable==$idSubCat_subtable) {
                        $Subquery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM subtable 
                                     WHERE username='$log_username' AND idCat = '$rowId ' 
                                     ORDER BY subcategories ASC " ;
                        $subtable_result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $Subquery);
                        while ( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($subtable_result)) {
                            $catid = $row1[0];// id of subcategorie
                            $subCat = $row1[2];
                            echo "<li>$subCat<br/>";
                            echo '<ul>';
                            $bill_query = "SELECT * FROM billTable 
                                           WHERE username='$log_username' 
                                           AND idSubCat = '$catid ' 
                                           AND month(uploaddate) = '$month_query' 
                                           AND year(uploaddate) = '$year_query'  
                                           ORDER BY cname ASC " ;
                            $bill_result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $bill_query);
                            while ( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($bill_result)) {
                                $bill_name = $row1[5];
                                $bill_name_cname = $row1[6];
                                $bill_name_filename= $row1[9];
                                echo "<li><a href='#'>$bill_name</a><br/>";
                            }
                            echo '</ul></li>';
                        }
                        echo '</ul></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    echo '</ul></li>';
    echo '</ul></li>';
    echo '</ul></li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

[image: sreenshot]

of above code

Comment: You're question is very vaque and it's better if you provided the db structure instead of how you describe it

Comment: I think it is best that you look into using joins...

If you were to use this code it could cause your server to be unresponsive with just one user. 

I am sorry I did not answer the question, but this logic will not work out well.

Comment: thnx Martin for pointing this performance issue , I also was thinking there is lots of query, could take some time in execution making it slow. I am looking another logic to make it fast . Suggest  me some method if u could. I am new in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check using count()

```
$count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM billTable WHERE username='$log_username' AND idSubCat = '$catid ' AND month(uploaddate) = '$month_query' AND year(uploaddate) = '$year_query'  ORDER BY cname ASC ";
```

then before you echo the subcategory check

```
if($count_query > 0){
      $catid = $row1[0];// id of subcategorie
      $subCat = $row1[2];
      echo "<li>$subCat<br/>";
      echo '<ul>';

      $bill_query = "SELECT * FROM billTable WHERE username='$log_username' AND idSubCat = '$catid ' AND month(uploaddate) = '$month_query' AND year(uploaddate) = '$year_query'  ORDER BY cname ASC " ;
      $bill_result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $bill_query);
      while ( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($bill_result)){
              $bill_name = $row1[5];
              $bill_name_cname = $row1[6];
              $bill_name_filename= $row1[9];
              echo "<li><a href='#'>$bill_name</a><br/>";

       } 
       echo '</ul></li>';
    }
```

Comment: if you found it helpful, would you mark as the solution, than you.